# C++ Strange std::bad_alloc exception

Tags: c++, exception, std

So I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
const int MAXN = 1000000;
int isNotPrime[MAXN];
vector<int> primes;

void sieve()
{
    for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt(MAXN); ++i)
    {
        if(isNotPrime[i]) continue;
        for(int j = i*i; j <= MAXN; j += i)
        {
            isNotPrime[j] = true;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 2; i <= MAXN; ++i)
    {
        if(!isNotPrime[i])
        {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    sieve();
    return 0;
}
```

What I cannot understand is why my program throws a std::bad_alloc exception when it executes. Even more mind-boggling is that when I swap the lines `int isNotPrime[MAXN];` and `vector<int> primes;` the programs executes as intended.
Swapped like this:

```
vector<int> primes;
int isNotPrime[MAXN];
```

Comment: 1) What debugging have you done?  What line throws the exception.  2) Nothing is "mind boggling" if you've corrupted memory.

Comment: you're overrunning your array. `isNotPrime[j] = true` with `j <= MAXN` isn't going to bode well when `j` reaches `MAXN`. In doing so, you're stomping on the next variable in memory, which appears to be your vector, and its first data member, which is likely the pointer to the vectors dynamic memory bed. overwrite that, and boom. There should be no  `... <= MAXN` in this code *at all*. It should be `... < MAXN`

Comment: Obvious oddity is the for loops like `i <= MAXN` can lead to accessing invalid memory (since the array is 0..MAXN-1)

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. But Why does it work correctly when the mentioned lines are swapped then?

Comment: Read the full comment. the code is still invalid and the program ill-formed, but by rearranging the vars you relocated where in memory the overwrite happens to something no-so-critical as the dynamic memory pointer of your vector. Regardless, its still wrong, and should be addressed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= MAXN; ++i)
```

The check should be `i < MAXN` instead.  (Or, make the array have size `MAXN + 1`.)

At some point, the `isNotPrime[MAXN] = true;` executes, which overflows the bounds of the array, causing *undefined behaviour*.  In practice, this overwrites some internal field of the next variable (`primes`), which confuses the `std::vector` implementation, probably causing it to request a lot of memory.

This also explains why switching the variable order "fixes" it, because now you're scribbling over something else instead of `primes`.